# How to speed up MySQL UPDATE queries to get better performances per second

Tags: php, mysql, database

To get better performances on my website, I have to change all `INSERT` queries to store them first on a CSV file and then automatically import them to a specific table using `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

But what about UPDATE ?

I have around 10000 updates per second, how it's possible to get that result ?

For each request i get 2 `UPDATES` (With prepared statement):

```
UPDATE player_tb SET coins = coins + ? WHERE player_id = ?
UPDATE score_tb SET score = score + ? WHERE player_id = ?
```

In both tables `player_td` and `score_tb` I indexed `player_id` column:

```
ALTER TABLE player_tb ADD INDEX(player_id);
ALTER TABLE score_tb ADD INDEX(player_id);
```

I want at least get 40k updates per second, do you have a way to achieve this goal please ?

Thank you

Comment: *"I want at least get 40k updates per second, do you have a way to achieve this goal please ?"* 40K update a second on one server? That's like 0.000025 seconds per update..it will alteast take around 0.0002 second (if not more) to parse (and possible optimize) a complex query on average and check permission not to mention writing to the disk. Consider [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/340e01/791) where a simple `SELECT 1` already takes 0.000012 + 0.000003 = 0.000015 to be parsed and permission checked.

Comment: *"I want at least get 40k updates per second, do you have a way to achieve this goal please ?"* But there is a way using [MySQL Cluster](https://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/) to scale out the load between multiple fysical servers.  Then it's is possible to get a very [high](https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/benchmarks/mysql-cluster/) performing cluster.

Comment: @RaymondNijland MySQL cluster is a solution i think, do you have any tutorial on how to setup this ? A way to make a load balancing between database (For example storing or updating datas realtime on different servers.) Thank you again